# Meteor with leaflet killing my browser

Tags: meteor, leaflet

I'm trying to build a reactive map with Meteor and leaflet to show some site visitors. Everything works fine up to a point (about 30 mins of leaving the browser open) when the map stop being so responsive and it dies pretty soon.

I tried clearing markers before adding new ones and keeping my map as clean as possible with no success. Heres my code:

On `document.ready`:

```
visitors_map = new L.Map('visitors-map').setView([24, 17], 3);
markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'packages/leaflet/images';

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/api_key/26250/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(visitors_map);
Session.set("visitors_map_rendered", true);
```

On `Deps.autorun`:

```
if (Session.get("visitors_map_rendered")) {
    visitors_map.removeLayer(markers);
    var markerList = [];

    var visitors = Visitors.find();
    visitors.forEach(function(visitor) {
        markerList.push(L.marker([visitor.geo.latitude, visitor.geo.longitude]));
    });

    markers.clearLayers();
    markers.addLayers(markerList);
    visitors_map.addLayer(markers);
    visitors_map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds().pad(0.3));
}
```

Does anyone sees anything bad in my code? Is there anything I forgot to clear and "adds up" slowing my browser?

Comment: Maybe your object Visitors?

Comment: Have you wrapped your leaflet map container in a `{{#constant}}` container?

Comment: yes I did. Forgot to mention sorry.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak.

Comment: Agree with the memory leak @AndrewMao; Leaflet also has problems adding very large (geospatially) image overlays. Are you adding large (geospatially) image overlays? https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2825